# Podcasts about JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript, podcast

As a passionate JavaScript developer, I'd like to know if there's any quality Podcasts out there, devoted to JavaScript. (Both video and audio).

I am currently subscribing to:

- [YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/)
- [Audible Ajax](http://ajaxian.com/by/category/podcasts)

Comment: One additional one for the list that in not specifically javascript, but still a great one for web developers is http://thechangelog.com/

Answer (score 15):

[The JavaScript Show](http://www.javascriptshow.com) just launched and, I may be biased, but think it's pretty awesome.

Comment: For a non-biased opinion, this is a GREAT show for keeping up w/ new opensource projects in javascript (just recently became a big fan!).  

The yayquery podcast also mentioned is great compliment to The Javascript Show by focusing more on techniques or indepth talks on less projects per show.  Sadly, that one is not as regular.

Comment: The Javascript Show is pretty awesome indeed. +1

Answer (score 7):

I really like the yayquery podcast ([http://yayquery.com/](http://www.yayquery.com/))
There's also the official jquery podcast (http://feeds.feedburner.com/jQueryPodcast)

They are both pretty new. I like the yayquery podcast more because it feels more low-level. They talk about plugins and optimization and "hiddenhancements". The jquery podcast is more abstract. They talk about things like the direction of jquery and overall goals and motivations for the language.

The yayquery is audio or video. The jquery podcast is only audio.

Answer (score 3):

There's been a couple of good ones recently on Hanselminutes (http://www.hanselminutes.com/) where he's spoken to a blind developer about useability, an interview with John Resig (jQuery creator), and several others.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the OpenWeb Podcast:

http://openwebpodcast.com/